# How can I launch Openbox when I log in?

Tags: greeter, window-manager

I read a few articles about the super-minimal window manager [Openbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox).

I would like to set it up on elementary OS, but it's just not a desktop environment. I would like to run Openbox after I login (just like I can select Kodi). How can I do that?

Are there other recommendations that I have to take to implement Openbox successfully?

Comment: I did find a bit here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Openbox

Comment: Can you explain a little - does selecting it from to gear not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this in a clean way, you will have to create a custom GNOME session file and a X Server session file (first, install openbox via `sudo apt-get install openbox obconf menu` of course). Let's take a look at the two files currently present:

- `/usr/share/xsessions/pantheon.desktop` (X Server session file):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pantheon
Comment=This session provides elementary experience
Exec=gnome-session --session=pantheon
TryExec=wingpanel
Icon=
Type=Application
```

- `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/pantheon.session` (GNOME session file for Pantheon):

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Pantheon
RequiredComponents=gala;gnome-settings-daemon;
FallbackSession=ubuntu
DesktopName=Pantheon
```

So, to create your own Openbox session, you need to create two new files:

- `/usr/share/xsessions/pantheon-openbox.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Pantheon-Openbox
Comment=This session provides a custom Openbox experience
Exec=gnome-session --session=pantheon-openbox
TryExec=wingpanel
Icon=
Type=Application
```

- `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/pantheon-openbox.session`

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Pantheon-Openbox
RequiredComponents=openbox;gnome-settings-daemon;
FallbackSession=ubuntu
DesktopName=Pantheon-Openbox
```

You are now able to select your custom session upon login.

Keep in mind that neither Wingpanel nor the GNOME technology stack is really created for working with such a session - while it might work, you can expect rough edges. I really would not recommend to use it that way, but it's an answer to your question. Use on your own risk, of course. **There is no real benefit Openbox is offering over Gala, especially in terms of integration with technologies used by elementary OS.**